# Make new bitmap on the canvas from resource

Tags: android, android-canvas

I think that my problem is minor but I can't find solution. I am trying to make application which will help me to make WEB pages and I want to make application which will put graphic element on the screen.

I made drawable png images of rectangles and I can put them on the screen where I want, no problem, but I can not make new graphic/bitmap.

How I can put new graphics object on the screen when I press in meni DIV or iFrame?

```
public class Objects extends View {
    private float X;
    private float Y;
    private Paint myPaint;
    final String C_DIV = "DIV";
    final String C_TABLE = "Table";
    final String C_IFRAME = "iFrame";
    final String C_LIST = "List";
    Canvas canvas;
    Bitmap divimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.div);
    Bitmap iframeimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.iframe);
    Bitmap img = null;
    String objectname = " ";

    public Objects(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myPaint = new Paint();
    }

    public void HTMLObjects(String object) {
        Log.d(object, "see");
        if (object.equals(C_DIV)) {
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(divimg);
            objectname = "DIV";
        }
        if (object.equals(C_IFRAME)) {
            myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(iframeimg);
            objectname = "iFrame";
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (img != null) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(img, X - 50, Y - 50, myPaint);
            canvas.drawText(objectname, X, Y - 50, myPaint);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

This is a class which I am calling from the activity Workspace with

```
ob.HTMLObjects((String) item.getTitle());
```

and I am sending information which menu is pressed.

I do not know how to make new/different object/bitmap when I pressed DIV or iFrame.

Comment: It seems you know how to create `Bitmap` from resource using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`. I don't fully understand what you want.

Comment: I want to make copy of the bitmap. When I press meni DIV I want new bitmap, old bitmap will stay on postion where I lived it and I want make new bitmap which I will put on the new position. Sorry on my English.

Comment: It seems you already have code that does it. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Does't work, when I choose another optinon from menu I got new bitmap and old is deleted, old object/bitmap not stayed on the screen.

Comment: I tried with new canvas and new bitmap but without succeed, It is possible to make for example, new bitmap or new divimg.

Comment: Can you explain how does touch event and menu event should work in more details? It seems you need to store somewhere list of already added bitmaps. Probably instead of `img` in `Objects` class you need to use `List<Bitmap> imgs` for all added images.

Comment: Ok, in the activity Workspace() I am using onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), from that activity I am calling class objects() and I am sending (String) item.getTitle() to Object class. In the object() class I use item.getTitle() to choose which object is preesed ( function HTMLObjects(String object))  in the if statments decided which text and bitmap will be used, after that bitmap is putted on the screen on I can moved around. I hope that you mean on that. Now I will try to do that will List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these version. I replaces `x`,`y`,`img`,`objectname` with according lists:

```
public class Objects extends View {
    private Paint myPaint;
    public final String C_DIV="DIV";
    public final String C_TABLE="Table";
    public final String C_IFRAME="iFrame";
    public final String C_LIST="List";
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap divimg= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.div);
    private Bitmap iframeimg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.iframe);
    private List<Bitmap> images;
    private List<Float> xs;
    private List<Float> ys;
    private List<String> objectNames;

    public Objects(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myPaint = new Paint();
        images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        xs = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ys = new ArrayList<Float>();
        objectNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void HTMLObjects(String object){
        Log.d(object, "see");
        if (object.equals(C_DIV)) {
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            images.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(divimg));
            objectNames.add("DIV");
            xs.add(0F);
            ys.add(0F);
        }
        if (object.equals(C_IFRAME)){
            myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            images.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(iframeimg));
            objectNames.add("iFrame");
            xs.add(0F);
            ys.add(0F);
        }
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action=event.getAction();
        if (xs.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        int pos = xs.size() - 1;
        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xs.set(pos, event.getX());
                ys.set(pos, event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                xs.set(pos, event.getX());
                ys.set(pos, event.getY());
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            float x = xs.get(i);
            float y = ys.get(i);
            canvas.drawBitmap(images.get(i), x-50, y-50, myPaint);
            canvas.drawText(objectNames.get(i), x, y-50, myPaint);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```